# internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException Cannot find module in Node

Tags: node.js, express

I am configuring Server Side Rendering on my app and I need to use React components to used them server side, so I am using module type in `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
  ...
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.7",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.17",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "nodemon": "2.0.4",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build",
    "dev:build-server": "SET NODE_ENV=development & webpack --config webpack.server.js --mode=development -w",
    "dev:start": "nodemon ./server-build/index.js",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel build dev:*"
  }
}
```

This allows to use imports, but I am having problems with the paths:

[image]

This is solved if I add js extension, but If I do that, I get another error:

> The requested module './routers/post.js' does not provide an export
> named 'default'

This is the server configuration:

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import React from 'react';
import express from 'express';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server.js';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { API_VERSION } from './config.js';
import Home from './client/src/pages/Home';

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

// Load routings
import userRoutes from "./routers/user";
import postRoutes from "./routers/post";
import commentsRoutes from "./routers/comment";
import policyRoutes from "./routers/policy";

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

const uri = "MONGODB_URL"
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    console.log("DB connected.");
  }
})

// Configue http
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method"
    );
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    res.header("Allow", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    next();
});

app.use(`/api/${API_VERSION}`, userRoutes);
app.use(`/api/${API_VERSION}`, postRoutes);
app.use(`/api/${API_VERSION}`, commentsRoutes);
app.use(`/api/${API_VERSION}`, policyRoutes);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const home = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Home />);

  const indexFile = path.resolve('./client/build/index.html');
  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
      return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
    }

    return res.send(
      data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${home}</div>`)
    );
  });
});

app.use(express.static('./build'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running!`)
})
```